# Wireless Atheros Qualcomm AR9285 not working

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, atheros

My WiFi doesn't work. However, a driver is claimed. There is no soft nor hard block.

The laptop I'm dealing with is a Lenovo B570e. On the link below you can see this is a verified laptop for the use of Ubuntu.

http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/catalog/component/pci/168c%3A002b/

I also tried this, which gave me a bunch of errors.

> Download this drivers: compat-wireless-3.6.8-1.tar.bz2
>
> Install the drivers:
>
> tar -xf /path/to/compat-wireless-3.6.8-1.tar.bz2
>
> cd /path/to/compat-wireless-3.6.8-1
>
> ./scripts/driver-select ath9k
>
> make
>
> sudo make install
>
> Reboot your computer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to install that driver since your wireless card is supported out of the box.

Run the command
`rfkill list all`

You will get an output similar to

**Wireless LAN**

**Soft blocked: yes/no**

**Hard blocked: yes/no**

To unblock, enter the command

`sudo rfkill unblock all`

Comment: rfkill list all gives me this

0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
Nothing blocked.